# Using string.gsub to change x to y most efficiently (Lua)

Tags: lua, gsub

I'm at a loss here, though I've been getting more and more familiar with gsub in Lua.  There probably is a better way to do this more efficiently, and that's what I'm looking for.  What I'm wishing to do is change:

```
\(port Planes)9e;\(enter pool)n2euw
```

into

```
port Planes;run 9e;enter pool;run n2euw
```

It seems like it would be a simple thing, but I'm totally drawing a blank.  I could probably attribute that partly to being exhausted, but that's not really an excuse.  The way I would have it is:

```
string.gsub(variable, ";","\(")
string.gsub(variable, "\(", ";")
string.gsub(variable, ")",";run")
string.gsub(variable, ";;",";")
```

But to me, that looks pretty sloppy, and not as efficient as I would like it to me.  It also poses the problem if ")" ends the line, and it'd put ";" there, which is not something I want.  I would appreciate the expertise of someone more familiar with Lua who can tidy this up and make it more efficient.  I'll be putting it into a function once all is said and done.  Thanks!

Edit: Upon testing that, it doesn't even work, anyway... and I can't figure out the proper pattern matching sequence to use to make it work at all...

Comment: Is there some reason why "efficiency" is a concern?

Comment: Faster code compilation, I suppose.  Plus, it makes it easier to view in the future so I don't look at it later and say 'What in the world was I trying here?'  The ultimate result I'm looking for is just a tidier way to do it; it'll help me with future projects in the future as well, since I'm still learning Lua.

Comment: Don't forget that strings are immutable, so you need to actually remember the result of each call to `string.gsub`: `variable = string.gsub(variable, ";;",";")`. I'd also save some typing and write it as `variable = variable:gsub(";;",";")` as long as I was sure that `variable` is always a `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing more about the possible combinations you could have, I can't say that this would work in every instance but it should give a start:

```
string.gsub(variable,"\\%((.-)%)","%1;run ")
string.gsub(variable,";run $","")
```

The first gsub is returning the commands inside your parenthesis, removing the parenthesis and adding ';run ' at the end.

The second one is checking whether the end of the string is ';run ' and replacing it if that's the case.

You should also check out this article for a nice summary on patterns:
http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html

Comment: This makes things so much tidier.  I truly was drawing a blank on it, and I appreciate your answer!